# How to get MongoDB to efficiently count millions of documents in buckets

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in MongoDB 7 with millions of documents that look like this:

```json
{
  _id: ...,
  event_type: "view",
  programId: "12345",
  timestamp: ISODate("2024-01-01T00:00:00Z")
}
```

There are indexes on the `timestamp` and `programId` fields.

I would like to create an aggregation pipeline that counts the number of events per day (or week, or month, or quarter, etc.) for a given `programId`. It seems like a simple problem but I can't figure out how to get MongoDB to do it in an efficient way.

I've tried the following approaches:

- a `$group` stage which uses `$dateTrunc` on the `timestamp` field as the `_id`
- a `$bucket` stage with predefined buckets for each day/week/etc
- a `$facet` stage with a `[$match, $count]` pipeline for each desired aggregation bucket
- all of the above, with and without an indexed `$match` stage preceding them

None of these approaches have the performance I want. Some of them use `IXSCAN` while some end up using `COLLSCAN`, but they all take over a second to execute (and surprisingly, they're often slower when using an index than without).

If I instead try to find the count for only a single bucket with a simple `[$match, $count]` pipeline, MongoDB uses `COUNT_SCAN` and returns in 2ms. Is there a way to get this kind of performance while aggregating over multiple (possibly dozens or hundreds) of buckets?

I realize an [on-demand materialized view](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/materialized-views/) or similar approach would solve my problem, but considering the information I want is readily available in the index I would prefer not to introduce that complexity if it could be done with a simple pipeline instead.

Comment: Have you tried preparing the dates for grouping on the documents (e.g. storing the day value or the result of `$dateToParts`) and creating a compound index over `programId` and the prepared date field(s)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make use of indexes, you should not use the `$dateTrunc` in the aggregation itself. If you are able to change the schema, you could pre-calculate the values that you want to count the values for. If you only want to get counts for a programId by day, you could store the result of a `$dateTrunc` in a field `day`. If you want to be a bit more flexible, you could use [`$dateToParts`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/) that splits a timestamp into an object with properties for year, month, day, hour and so on.

I run a test on my machine with 10 million documents with a schema similar to this sample:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "programId": "93544",
  "timestamp": {
    "$date": "2024-01-23T15:06:00.000Z"
  },
  "parts": {
    "year": 2024,
    "month": 1,
    "day": 23
  }
}
```

After creating the index `programId_1_parts.year_1_parts.month_1_parts.day_1` on both the program id and the parts, I ran the following aggregation with a very good performance:

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      programId: "11596",
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: "$parts.year",
        month: "$parts.month",
        day: "$parts.day",
      },
      cnt: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
]
```

The reason is that the query is covered by the index and thus can be served from memory.

Your mileage may vary, but I hope this helps to speed things up.